# Can I select values from one column in an php-array?

Tags: php, mysql

I need only the values of one column in an array. Without php I would use "SELECT valueX FROM tableY".
This does not work with php. I only get one result.
This is what I have:

```
$salty = "SELECT salt FROM login";
$salts = mysqli_query($connection, $salty);
$validsalts = mysqli_fetch_array($salts);
```

Comment: question lack detail, try echo in loop!!

Comment: do u have only single record in your database ?

Comment: ```var_dump($validsalts);``` may be of use

Comment: you can use loop [while loop for example]  to get multiple records while($validsalts = mysqli_fetch_array($salts)){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a loop iteration for fetching the all value.

for example.

```
$salty = "SELECT salt FROM login";
$salts = mysqli_query($connection, $salty);
while($validsalts = mysqli_fetch_array($salts))
{
    echo $validsalts['salt'];
}
```